# Document Text Detection API respond error "Bad image data" since July 25 or later

Tags: python, google-cloud-vision

The release of Google Cloud Vision API had been on July 24, but what else was there later?

There was no problem when using Document Text Detection of Vision API on July 25, but when I did the same thing on Augst 1, it became a error response "Bad image data".
Not all images causes this error.  Several images causes "Bad image data" response.
Using the not Document Text Detection but Text Detection API, I can get the correct response.

Does anyone else have the same problem?

My code is following.

```
import io
import os

# Imports the Google Cloud client library
from google.cloud import vision
from google.cloud.vision import types

def detect_document(path):
    """Detects document features in an image."""
    client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()

    with io.open(path, 'rb') as image_file:
        content = image_file.read()

    image = types.Image(content=content)

    response = client.document_text_detection(image=image)
    document = response.full_text_annotation
    print response

    for page in document.pages:
        for block in page.blocks:
            block_words = []
            for paragraph in block.paragraphs:
                block_words.extend(paragraph.words)

            block_symbols = []
            for word in block_words:
                block_symbols.extend(word.symbols)

            block_text = ''
            for symbol in block_symbols:
                block_text = block_text + symbol.text

            print(block_text)
            print(block.bounding_box)

detect_document('test.jpg')
```

Response is following.

```
error {
  code: 3
  message: "Bad image data."
}
```

Comment: I am with GCP support. We had another similar case stating the same. Since there are not public updates regarding a change on Document Text Detection, I asked a Vision API specialist to check both issues.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
Please let me know when the problem is fixed.

Comment: There have been many improvements released for the Cloud Vision API over time, including optimizations to the image processing behavior. [This documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/supported-files) describes the image types that should be supported. If some of the image types are being rejected, this is an issue that we should investigate further. Can you provide the image that is generating the error? I can already see the code, that is the other useful part to reproduce the error.

Comment: I have uploaded the image that causes error response. Please check it.  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1efm9UQ8sHey5l-O_NommqdnNjDXolet2/view

Comment: @Hayato Could you try to convert this image to a [supported image type](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/supported-files)? I tried doing this to PNG, and then, uploading this image to a bucket in Cloud Storage, and then, [try to get the text results in the API tester](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/ocr#try_it). It worked for me in this way, let's see if it works also for you.

Comment: It's a JPEG file supported image type. 
I've got a result by converting JPEG to PNG as you say.
However, it is different from the previous result json. I had got 3.6 MB of result json in June 1st, but now I've got only 2.5 MB.
Had I better upload the json?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I meant using a lossless image type. You tried from your code or from the tester I linked? If it's the former, try also [using the Beta library](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/beta-libraries#installing_the_client_library) Maybe something changed in the model?

Comment: I had tried my code and [this tester](https://cloud.google.com/vision/).
And then, I tried using [the Beta Library](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/beta-libraries#installing_the_client_library). 
Both work for the my image by PNG, but not by JPEG.

Sorry, I didn't try the tester you linked, because I couldn't find it in [this page](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/ocr#try_it).

Comment: My code and the same JPEG are work now! Thank you  Rubén C., Mangu and GCP support.